# Searchkick and Regular Expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to build an advanced search option (similar to [Twitter's](https://twitter.com/search-advanced)). Users can enter the words included, words excluded, words containing, exact phrase, and such in a search query. [image: Twitter Advanced Search]

I'm using Searchkick to do this. Particularity [Searckick's regexp](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queries) searches.

Here is what I'm doing to find the companies which have the words "Facebook or less" in their slogans.

`Company.search("Be", where: { short_desc: /.*(#{ar}).*/ })`

This works well. But, how would I do a negative of this search?

Doing something like, `Company.search("Be", where: { short_desc: /.*(?!(#{ar})).*/ })` is not yielding results. Also, can I combine a search that has words to be included AND words to be excluded?
[image: Searchkick Example]

Comment: Here's a little cheatsheet for anyone encountering the same problem,

   # match all = Company.search("Be", where: { short_desc: /.*(#{ar}).*/ })

   # match not = Company.search("Be", where: { short_desc: {not: /.*(#{ar}).*/} })

   # match combi = Company.search("Be", where: { short_desc: {not: /.*(#{ar}).*/}, short_desc: /.*git.*/ })

Comment: How to create regex to match exact phrase in where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this helps you, try this:

```
Business.search("Be", where: { short_desc: {not: /.*(#{ar}).*/} })
```

And check the results. You can combine this with `AND` or `OR` operators. Anywhere using the `where` clause. Extracted from the gem readme file:

```
where: {
  expires_at: {gt: Time.now}, # lt, gte, lte also available
  orders_count: 1..10,        # equivalent to {gte: 1, lte: 10}
  aisle_id: [25, 30],         # in
  store_id: {not: 2},         # not
  aisle_id: {not: [25, 30]},  # not in
  user_ids: {all: [1, 3]},    # all elements in array
  category: /frozen .+/,      # regexp
  or: [
    [{in_stock: true}, {backordered: true}]
  ]
}
```

This is how you can combine it with query.

Hope this helps.